# Laravel I want to get string value from {{$string}} directives and pass to <?php ?> area in blade file in ,I am passing a value in $pagename var

Tags: php, laravel

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="summary-ckeditor" name="description">
<?php
    $data =file_get_contents(resource_path('views/{{$pagename}}.blade.php'));
?>
{{$data}}
</textarea>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here, but if you want te include a blade file as partial you can use `@include('views.' . $pagename)` . The php block is not needed. Off the record: use `@php @endphp`  rather then using `<?php ?>` in blade files.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `<?php ?>` tags you work as in standard php, so to concatenate string you may use `.` operator.

```
$data = file_get_contents( resource_path( 'views/' . $pagename . '.blade.php'));
```

or if you including view in blade template you may try `@include` directive

```
@include('views.' . $pagename )
```

Comment: yes, but why, explain your answer.  Can i get some credit for the right answer you added :-D

Comment: Apart from that, the first part of your answer shouldn't be there. not everything that works, is a right answer.